# Magento: query to export product without category + attribute VISIBILITY

Tags: sql, magento

I have a query to SELECT all products that aren't associated to a category.
Here query:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product as ccp
on cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id
WHERE category_id IS NULL
```

Now I would see values of attribute **visibility** (*Catalog, Search, Catalog and Search, Not Visible Individually*)

This attribute value is on this table: catalog_productentity_ind where attribute id is 89.

```
SELECT *
FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE `attribute_id` =89
```

Now I would show attribute values (attribute_id=89) where category is NULL like this example:

product id | product SKU | value of attribute (id 89) | category (is NULL for all)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpe_int.value as visibility 
FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product as ccp
on cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as cpe_int
ON cpe.entity_id = cpe_int.entity_id
AND cpe_int.attribute_id = 89
WHERE ccp.category_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Works but ther is a syntax error on the first line: after word "visibility" there is no comma...than works perfect.

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks.